# Populating Jquery Multiselect with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to populate a Jquery MultiSelect from a list of values retrieved from an ajax call. Currently, the call is successful however the Multiselect has nothing populated and no values are stored in the html. Would someone mind helping me out with this? I have looked for other answers, but couldn't find any similar enough to mine.

Ajax function

```
function loadProjects(office_id){
    var $select = $("#Projects").multiselect(); // Apply multiselect
    $select.multiselect('disable'); //disable it initially
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/Projects/" + office_id,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $('#Projects').multiselect('enable');
            $('#Projects').empty();
            // $('#Projects').append('<option value="">Select a Project</option>');
            if (data.length  == 0){
                $('#Projects').append("<option class='text-danger' value='0' disabled> No Projects under this Chief.</option> ");
                $('#Projects').append("<option class='text-danger' value='0' disabled> Enter the Project manually.</option> ");
            }
            else{
                // Populate Projects box.
                var i;
                for(i=0; i< data.length;i++)
                {
                    var option = "<option value='" + data[i].project_id + ">" + data[i].project_name +  " </option>";
                    // console.log(option);
                    $('#Projects').append(option);
                    // $("#Projects").multiselect("rebuild");
                }
                $("#Projects").attr('multiple', 'multiple'); 
                $("#Projects").multiselect('rebuild');
            }
            
            

        }
    })
    
}
```

head tags

```
<!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static',filename='css/styles.css')}}"> 
    <!-- AJAX/ JQUERY -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!-- Multiselect -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />
```

```
<select class="form-select select select-Projects" id="Projects" name="Projects"  ></select>
```

response from ajax call

```
[
    {
    "office_id": xxx,
    "project_id": xxx,
    "project_name": "xxxxxxxx",
    "CE_name": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "CE_unit": "xxx",
    "CE_EFIS": "xxxx",
    "district_id": xx
},
]
```

Comment: Is there an element with an ID of `Projects`? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67646160/edit) to include your HTML.

Comment: The select tag, has an Id of Projects

Comment: Please show an example of `data`.

Comment: Data can be seen now at the bottom.

Comment: HI, you are missing boostrap cdn add that it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in this line:

```
var option = "<option value='" + data[i].project_id + ">" + data[i].project_name +  " </option>";
```

You are missing the closing apostrophe:

```
var option = "<option value='" + data[i].project_id + "'>" + data[i].project_name +  " </option>";
```

Also, you're referring to `data[i].project_id` and `data[i].project_name` but those keys (`project_id` and `project_name`) do not appear in the sample data you provided.

Comment: I fixed the closing apostrophe, and updated my 'data' variable. The first example data was a mistake. The question now properly reflects how data is structured, however my multiselect still does not populate, or show any values.

Comment: @JaredBenitez I'm guessing it's a conflict with different versions of the various JS libraries you're pulling in. [This Codepen](https://codepen.io/km0ser/pen/eYvvrQq) shows a working, simple example of destroying, populating, and rebuilding a multiselect.

Comment: I believe that this was in fact the problem. I was missing a particular bundle of bootstrap/javascript libraries, after including these they worked.